# Display a web page in a container, scroll, switch to next

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, x-frame-options

I have a list of urls I need to show on a screen for a presentation. After the page have loaded, I want to scroll to the end of the page, and when it's reached load the next one.

The problem is, most of those pages have 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin', so I can't use iframes. What other options do I have ?

I thought about, maybe, a chrome extension will complete rights over navigation that would handle the whole process...

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I don't think there is a pure website solution, but you could make a Chrome extension that does it (by setting [all_frames to true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and injecting code into the iframes that does whatever you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was indeed to build a Chrome extension. Only the software containing the page gives you that much control over it when you don't have access to its code - namely, the browser.

I built a very simple extension using `chrome.tabs` in the background to open a new tab or update it, injecting a script in the page whenever it's loaded, and using messaging to inform the background when scrolling is finished and it's time to load a new page in the list.